# How to extract a number in between square brackets to another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I hope someone out there can assist me with my query below.

I need to extract data from one column in excel to another,  I am trying to get the numbers in the square brackets [] on the list below to pull through to a separate column;

Column B on my spreadsheet

B1 Shirt Linen Lds Mandarin Collar White XS (THI18) [6205.20.00]

B2 Shirt Linen Lds Mandarin Collar White XL (THI18D) [6205.20.00]

B3 Shirt Linen Lds Mandarin Collar Stone XS (THI19) [6205.20.00]

B4 Shirt Linen Lds Mandarin Collar Stone S (THI19A) [6205.20.00]

B5 Shirt Linen Lds Mandarin Collar Stone L (THI19C) [6205.20.00]

So for example in Column C I would like to see on the number i.e 6205.20.00 in C1.

I tired using the below MID code, but Excel doesn't allow it:

```
=MID(B1, SEARCH(“[“, B1)+1, SEARCH(“]”,B1) – SEARCH(“[“,B1)-1)
```

Please help!!!

Greg

Comment: You are using the left and right double quotation marks (Codes 147 & 148). You need to be using the regular Quotation Mark (Code 34)

Comment: Your hyphen is also incorrect. It needs to be a Hyphen.  Yours is an En Dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks so much for the help @Gary's Student

I managed to get the formula working by altering your formula as follows:

```
=MID(B1;FIND("[";B1)+1;FIND("]";B1)-FIND("[";B1)-1)
```

I had to only change the commas from , to ;

Thanks again.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Change the double quotes and other character errors:

```
=MID(B1,FIND("[",B1)+1,FIND("]",B1)-FIND("[",B1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary thanks for the response, however the above doesn't work and gives me an error message. See screenshot below:

Comment: Can't upload a photo, the error says =  "there is a problem with this formula"

Comment: @Greg  Don't re-type my formula.  Copy/paste from my post.

Comment: I have copied and pasted and get the same error.

Comment: The formula works fine for me, copied and pasted both your text and the formula and it did as expected.

Comment: @Greg  This formula was written for **US Locale**.  The separator is the *comma* and `MID()` and `FIND()` are English versions of these functions.